# Minimal polynomial of finite Galois extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension. In this context, I heard people talk about *the minimal polynomial of $L/K$*. I want to understand what is exactly meant by that phrase.

What I suppose: Since $L/K$ is Galois, the extension is separable. Therefore, there is an element $\alpha \in L$ with $L = K(\alpha)$ (as every finite and separable extension in simple by the Primitive Element Theorem). Now I think *the minimal polynomial of $L/K$* is just the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$.

Could you tell me whether my thoughts are correct or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a finite galois extension has a finite number of intermediate subfields, a theorem of artin with this hypoteses grants that exists a so called “primitive” element so you are right, since a galois extension is a splitting field of a separable polynomial, you can see the extension equivalently as the splitting field of the minimum polynomial of the primitive element.